# How do I bring the filename into the data frame with read_excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory of excel files that will continue to grow with weekly snapshots of the same data fields. Each file has a date stamp added to the file name (e.g. "_2021_09_30").

Here are my source files:

I have figured out how to read all of the excel files into a python data frame using the code below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('NETWORK DRIVE DIRECTORY') 
files = os.listdir(cwd) 
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
     if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
         df = df.append(pd.read_excel(cwd+"/"+file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head()
```

Since these files are snapshots of the same data fields, I want to be able to track how the underlying data changes from week to week. So I would like to add/include a column that has the filename so I can incorporate the date stamp in downstream analysis.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the variable file seems to be your filiename. What do you want to do with it exactly?

Comment: I would like to add the filename to the dataframe so that when I union the data from the files together, I can see which file a given row came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I agree with the comments that it's not exactly clear what you're looking for, so maybe clearing that up will help us be more helpful.

For example, with the filename "A_FILENAME_2020-01-23", do you want to use the name "A_FILENAME", or "A_FILENAME_2020-01-23"? Or are you not sure, because you're trying to think through *how* to track this downstream?

If the latter approach, this is what you would do for adding a new column:

```
for file in files:
     if file.endswith('.xlsx'):

         tmp = pd.read_excel(cwd+"/"+file)
         tmp['filename'] = file
         df = df.Append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
```

This would allow you to search the table by the starting of the 'filename' column, and pull the discrete data of each snapshot of the file side by side. Unfortuantely, this is a LOT of data.

If you ONLY want to store differences, you'd be able to use the `.drop_duplicates` function to try to drop based off a unique value that you use to decide whether there's a new, modified, or deleted row: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

But, if you don't have a unique identifier for rows, that makes this quite a tough engineering problem. Very. Do you have a unique identifier you can use as your diffing strategy?

---

Extra code to split up the Files into separate columns for easier filtering later on (no harm in adding these, more columns the better I think):

```
from datetime import datetime

tmp['filename_stripped']=file[-11:]

tmp['filename_date']=datetime.strptime(file[:10], "%Y_%m_%d")
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out for clarification on this. Each of the xlsx files are a snapshot of the data at that time. As such, there will be duplicates between the files (meaning the same case_id could show up in multiple files). I am wanting to union all of the xlsx files into one dataframe and include the date from the filename so I can see what status the case_id was on a certain date and compare it to other dates.

Comment: Ah yes, the above should get you part of the way there then with tmp['filename'] = file. This will set that column's value on every row the file (with it's date) is used. 
If you want to get fancier and separate out the filename/date for easier filtering down the road, use the code I just added at the bottom and make 2 separate columns with it :) Happy coding!

Comment: thanks so much. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional column on the dataframe.

Modifying from your code

```
temp = pd.read_excel(cwd+"/"+file), ignore_index=True
temp['date'] = file[-11:]
df = df.append(temp)
```

Comment: I'm trying this out and it creates a [date] field in my df, but it is null. Would you nest this in the for loop? or put it afterward?

Comment: @zdelo You could try to debug it by changing
temp['date'] = file[-11:] to temp['date'] = 'foo'. If the [date] in df is filled with foo, the problem is in your file[-11:]. Keep in mind that I use [-11:] because I assumed your filename has '_2021_09_30' at the end.

Comment: I realize what happened. There was an issue elsewhere in my code that was causing the error. Thank you for the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **glob** to easily combine xlsx or csv files into one dataframe. You just have to copy-paste your files' absolute path to where it says "/xlsx_path". You can also change read_excel to read_csv if you have csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

all_files = glob.glob(r'/xlsx_path' + "/*.xlsx")
file_list = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files]
all_df = pd.concat(file_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively you can use the one-liner below:

```
all_df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel, glob.glob('/xlsx_path/*.xlsx')))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is much more efficient, but is there a way to incorporate the filename into the all_df dataframe? For instance, to append a column that would include the filename so that when I union the files, I can see which file a given row came from?

Comment: Hello, sorry for late response but here is the simple solution. Just add these lines between file_list and all_df.
~~~
file_names = [file.split('\\')[-1] for file in all_files]
for i in range(len(file_names)):
    file_list[i]['file_name'] = file_names[i]
~~~

Comment: `file_names = [file.split('\\')[-1] for file in all_files]`
`for i in range(len(file_names)):
    file_list[i]['file_name'] = file_names[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really want, but related to tracking changes, let's say you have 2 excel files, you can track changes doing the following :

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("file-1.xlsx")
df1

values
0   aa
1   bb
2   cc
3   dd
4   ee

df2 = pd.read_excel("file-2.xlsx") 
df2

values
0   aa
1   bb
2   cc
3   ddd
4   e
```

..and generate a new dataframe having rows that have changed between your 2 files :

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df = df.groupby(list(df.columns))

diff = [x[0] for x in new_df.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
df.reindex(diff)
```

Output :

```
    values
0   dd
1   ddd
2   e
3   ee
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment on this. I apologize that I wasn't clearer on my question. New files will be added to the directory each week with a new timestamp and I want to be able to merge all of the files together with the timestamp from the filename so I can know what file a given row comes from.